# Microsoft read aloud with bilingual(non-english) websites or pdf files

Tags: microsoft-edge

I see Microsoft [read aloud](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/32452/read-aloud-text-to-speech-a-pdf-file) feature is available in only one language at a time. That means you can select a language and ask edge to read a web page in that language. That is if your web page is written in multiple languages, for example a dictionary page(in this case there will be two languages in the same page), you can only make edge to read loud only one language but not both simultaneously.

Even though we select a regional language, I see read aloud picks english(of course only with local dialect) simultaneously with any language. That is you can read a web page which is written in English and another language, you can read words from both languages simultaneously without manually switching the language and voice.

But this feature is available only for any language in combination with English.

I would like to know if there is any way to read aloud two non-English languages simultaneously without manually switching the language or the voice.

Edited as per request from Community Bot

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community please check, If it is better now

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Edge Read Aloud feature is powered by [Text to Speech](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/products/cognitive-services/text-to-speech/), whose [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/language-support?tabs=stt-tts#supported-languages) has listed some of the languages that support **cross-lingual** feature (custom neural voice required). But apparently it has not been applied to Edge yet, since the feature needs to be purchased in Azure.

Comment: Are there any TTS engine which provides this feature now on any of the well known broswers?

Google assistant uses Google's TTS in adroid which is doing this.. but unfortunately I don't know of any way to get the feature on pc with chrome.

Comment: AFAIK, there has been no such built-in TTS engine on any of the modern browsers. The "Read Aloud" feature, IMO, only provides the basic function since speaking is not the core of a browser. The Google Assistant surely can do much better because it relies heavily on "speaking". If you have interest or a demand on TTS, you can consider purchasing for a better experience.